# How to keep scrolling a form when I reach the end or begging of a ListView.builder

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a widget father where I call a ListarCodigosLink widget, this widget store Cards and it is inside a red Container, i can scroll the items inside the listview, my problem is when i reach to end of the ListView.builder it doesn't go down. And when Ii reach the beggining of the ListView.build it doesn't go up, how can i resolve it?

this is my father widget:

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            codLinkInput(),
            buttonBuscaCliente(context),
            ayuda(context),
            ListaCodigosLink( 
              onItemTap: (codLink) {
                _codLinkController.text = codLink.toString();
                //ShowDialogPage.showMensajeDialog(context, "Por Favor Aguarde", "Estamos verificando la informacion de su codigo link", 0);
                tipoConsulta = 0;
                execute();
                //Navigator.of(context).pop();
              } 
            ),
        
        ReCaptchaWebView(
              width: 1,
              height: 1,
              webViewColor: null,
              onTokenReceived: _onTokenReceived,
              //url: 'https:yourdomain.com/index.html',
        ),
        visible == true ? _formulario() : Column(),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

and this is the ListaCodigosLink widget:

```
class ListaCodigosLink extends StatefulWidget {
  //ListaCodigosLink({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  ListaCodigosLink({Key? key, required this.onItemTap}) : super(key: key);

  final Function(int) onItemTap;
  

  @override
  State<ListaCodigosLink> createState() => _ListaCodigosLinkState();
}

class _ListaCodigosLinkState extends State<ListaCodigosLink> {

  final GlobalKey _listViewKey = GlobalKey();

  final codigoProvider = ProviderCodigo();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return identificadorUsuario == 0 ? Column() 
    : _listarCodigos();
    //: _listarCodigos2();
  }
  Widget _listarCodigos() {
    String token = tokenLogin['token'].toString();
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: codigoProvider.obtenerCodigos(token, identificadorUsuario),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
        }
        if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
        {
          return Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: const 
            [
              Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator()
              )
            ],
          );
        }       
        final datosDecodificados = json.decode(snapshot.data);
        final codigosLink = CodigosLink.fromJsonList(datosDecodificados);
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
            child: Container(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 350),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  width: 4.0,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),  // Radio de los bordes
              ),
              height: 350,
              child: ListView.builder(
                key: _listViewKey,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: codigosLink.items.length,
                itemBuilder: ( BuildContext context, int index ) {
                  return _listaObjetos(codigosLink.items[index], context);
                },
              )
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

[image]

Comment: You can use just top `SingleChildScrollView` and for the rest the use Column .

Answer (score 0):

Your widget tree is composed by the following widgets:

```
SingleChildScrollView
  > Column
    > ListaCodigosLink
      > FutureBuilder
        > SingleChildScrollView
          > Padding
            > Container
              > ListView
```

Note that you have three scrollables in the same tree: they'll most likely conflict with each other.

A fix to this is to remove the second `SingleChildScrollView`, since the `ListView` has a fixed height.

Comment: I have already removed the second SingleChildScrollView, but it doesnt work,